# Use of noun "immovable" and its plural form

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm not sure about the plural form of *immovable* (immovables). By the way, is "immovable" a word that English speakers use when referring to "real estates, properties etc."?

Answer (score 4):

"Immovable" (short for "immovable property"), as a noun, is a civil law term used to speak of property that cannot be moved or carried away, such as real estate. Moveable property, on the other hand, can be moved freely (think of cars, computers, et cetera).

As an example of its plural form, "We prepared a list of all moveables in the sale agreement."

See http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/395173/movable-and-immovable

Comment: I assume this comes from the French word *immeuble*; I believe it's strictly a legal term and not in general use.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I'm not sure how common *immeuble* is, but given that *meubles* is the standard wharehouse/shop sign for places selling the "moveable" stuff that goes *inside* buildings (basically, *furniture*), I doubt any French person would have a problem with the word in terms of meaning.

Comment: I meant *immovable* is a legal term, that it was translated from French to use in legal contexts (since English didn't have a word meaning exactly the same thing) and has only ever been used in law. My impression is that *immeuble* is reasonably common in French, but I don't know French well enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., at least, the conventional term is "real property", as opposed to "personal property", which can be moved.